# Delete Attempted Error

Tags: custom-field, account, custom

I am doing some tech debt clean up. Currently in the process of deleting 170 fields from the Account object. Today, however, I'm getting this error when attempting to delete. See screenshot[image]

I've attempted to log out and back in. I read it could be visual force related, but I havent' altered and VF pages or classes.

Do I need to refresh sandbox?

Comment: Have you tried switching to Classic mode? There might just be stone kind of glitch.

Comment: Anything special about the field e.g. depended in by another picklist (dependent picklist)? Depended on by code? Perhaps just a bad error message for a legitimate cause. Googling shows others have had this error message but I didn't find a solution posted.

Comment: @sfdcfox you were correct - appears to be just a glitch. Fixed itself in lighting. Thanks